# Read xml/rss-file from Wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, .htaccess

I've got a site "mysite.com", this has a rss/xml-feed located at mysite.com/feed.

I have to read this feed in a php-script but `simplexml_load_file` returns an empty result. How can I get the "real" path to the feed? I assume this file is created using some clever .htaccess and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with .htaccess. to get the feed you have two options.
one is using `file_get_content`, the other is using `cURL`.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/feed');
```

and

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://mysite.com/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

now the `$xml` hold the xml file, so you can use `simplexml_load_file` to parse it.

An alternative is you can use Rss PHP. more details are [here](http://rssphp.net/)